# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: Auto-mount partition

Tags: mount, partition, automounting

Here's the situation:
I have a nice 399 GB NTFS partition with a lot of files on it I access regularly but still need to access in Windows.
My question:
What is the best way to automount this partition on boot. If I can mount it before X loads, that'd be even better. A script or program would work.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be in search of `fstab`. The `fstab` file is read by the mount command automatically at boot time, and present in all flavors of linux I've encountered. For better reference consider reviewing the almighty [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab) on the subject.

In short you are probably looking to add a line to the `fstab` similar to:

```
/dev/my/partition    /my/mount/point   ntfs  defaults,noatime  0  2
```